# How to find indices of all empty rows in a sparse matrix,

Tags: julia

I have a large sparse matrix M. I would like to find the indices of all the empty rows in the matrix. How can you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia uses the [compressed sparse column (CSC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_column_(CSC_or_CCS)) format for sparse matrix storage, which means that the row index for all stored values are available. You can thus find all rows which have no stored value by taking the set difference between `1:NROWS` and the set of row indices:

```
julia> using SparseArrays

julia> A = rand(10, 10); A[3,:] .= 0; A[5,:] .= 0; S = sparse(A);

julia> idx = setdiff(Set(1:size(A, 1)), Set(S.rowval))
Set{Int64} with 2 elements:
  3
  5
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess size(A, 1) can be extracted from S?  I only have the sparse matrix

Comment: Ideally you could also use a higher level construct — like `all(iszero, S, dims=2)` — but I don't think that hits a sparse optimization right now.

Comment: And, no, you can use `1:size(S, 1)` (or even better: `axes(S, 1)`).